# Slick Slider Stack Photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

OK I know this question is a dino but still.. I cant find a solution across the web. The Slick slider is really stacking the images onload causing a delay for a couple of seconds. And I cant afford a delay for my carousel slider. I have tried the common solution like :

```
.slick-slider{
display:none;
}
.slick-initialized{
display:block;
}
```

I have also tried preloading the images so the browser can cache the image on or before loading it to my page for the actual transition but no luck. It Keep stacking the images.

Has anyone cross to this problem and found a way to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried different lazyloading in slick ? can you set the height for the slider?

Comment: @moped what lazyloading you mean the transition ? and how can I set the hieght of the slider ?

Comment: It also seems that whatever twicks I did in the css, once the .slick-initialized is present it keep stacking

Comment: slick supports lazyloading of images, ondemand and progressive, check the docs. for height, just set the height for the container. but "stacking" screenshot would be helpful here too

Comment: ok I have set the lazyload to ondemand and progressive, also set my container height to small until my class and slick-initialized is present. but its still stack. *face palm*